# Can't get two list items to go 'inline'

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm quite a novice in css and I'm stuck with something that is probably super easy and don't know where to ask! - in Wordpress support I've been gently rejected because they don't do css help.. :(

Here's my problem- I just can't get the two ul items to get inline:

http://cssdesk.com/Wm8yb

Comment: The parent - `.social` has a width of 60px.. remove that and either float the `li`, or set them to `inline-block`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I used both your and Jonathan's comment below and it worked.. thank you! Can I +1 your reply? - new here so not sure how it works exactly.. but thank you! :)

Comment: oh no I can't vote cause I haven't got 15rep. One day when I collect 15, I'll come back here and vote! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ul>` element is the one with the socialicons class.

Try:

```
ul.socialicons li
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I joined your and JoshCs reply above and it worked! Thanks a lot both, much much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

http://cssdesk.com/mJjJE

You'll need to increase the `.social` div's width to `90px` to let it fit both images, also you need to remove any `**ul**` because `.socialicons` belongs to the **ul** or just change the rules from:

```
.socialicons ul
```

to:

```
ul.socialicons
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Skatox, muchly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

use the  `display:inline`

or

```
float:left
```

Comment: Thanks PHP, appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to your css http://cssdesk.com/LAfFN

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good responses in this stack overflow thread: [CSS: display:inline-block and positioning:absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042467/css-displayinline-block-and-positioningabsolute)

You should also take note of Jonathan's reply that .socialicons is the ul.

With that said, if make the two following changes it will make the li elements inline.

```
.socialicons {
  list-style: none; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0; 
  padding-bottom: 0;
}  


.socialicons li {
    width:15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your CSS. You did not close your `<ul>` element and *the width of the `<ul>` is so small that it is squeezing the `<li>` elements into a single column*. You have also mixed up your CSS selector syntax. Instead of `.socialicons ul` it looks like what you want is `.socialicons`.

There are really only rare cases that you should use descendant selectors. CSS is parsed from right to left. See here for more about this: http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/

http://cssdesk.com/D8xrT

### HTML

```
<div class="social">
      <ul class="socialicons">
        <li id="facebook"><a href="#"><img alt="Facebook" src="http://placekitten.com/g/24/50" width="24" height="50" /></a></li>
        <li id="twitter"><a href="#"><img alt="Twitter" src="http://placekitten.com/g/30/50" width="30" height="50" /></a></li>        
      </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.social {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 1.5%;
  top: 5px;
  width: 75px;
}

.socialicons {
    list-style: none; 
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 0; 
  padding-bottom: 0;
}  


.socialicons li {
     display: inline-block;
   padding: 0.3em;
   float:left;
}  

.socialicons ol, ul {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.socialicons ul a {
    display: inline-block; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}


.socialicons img {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joshua! All of you people are lovely, really appreciate your help :)