# All widths set to width of widest element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've read a lot of tutorials about CSS flex boxes and CSS grids, but frankly I just can't figure out how to do this simple(?) thing.

All I want is for the elements in a container to all be as wide as the widest element.

I don't want them to fill up the whole width of the container, just all grow to the maximum width. Can that be done with CSS?

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <button>a normal button</button>
   <button>tiny</button>
   <button>a really, really, really wide button</button>
</div>
```

That produces something like this:

[image]

What I want is something like this, where they're all the width of that widest button:

[image]

I DON'T want them to just stretch out to fill the width of the page:

[image]

Can this be done? If so, what would be the CSS for the above HTML?

Comment: only CSS no. With js yes it's possible.

Comment: Its super simple just using CSS like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5dt3qq8d/)

Comment: @Jo He's specifically asking for the items not to stretch to the width of the container. As far as I know, flexbox cannot do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every item to have the same width as the widest element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159732/every-item-to-have-the-same-width-as-the-widest-element)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. This can be done with pure CSS.

**Here's a simple solution:**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <button>a normal button</button>
   <button>tiny</button>
   <button>a really, really, really wide button</button>
</div>
```

**Here's how it works:**

Grid Layout provides a unit for establishing flexible lengths in a grid container. This is the [**`fr`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit) unit. It is designed to distribute free space in the container (and is somewhat analogous to `flex-grow`).

However, the Grid spec provides for a particularly unique behavior when the container's width / height is dynamic (e.g., `display: inline-grid`, in this case).

In such cases, the `fr` unit will compute the `max-content` of each grid item. It will then take the maximum value it finds and use that as the `1fr` length for all items on the track.

That results in grid items that share the width of the widest item in the row.

Strange, but true.

It's also why a layout with [equal height rows is possible with Grid (but not flexbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44488357/3597276).

*Here's the relevant section in the spec:*

> [**7.2.3. Flexible Lengths: the `fr`
>   unit**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)
>
> ...
>
> When the available space is infinite (which happens when the grid
>   container’s width or height is indefinite), flex-sized (`fr`) grid tracks are
>   sized to their contents while retaining their respective proportions.
>
> The used size of each flex-sized grid track is computed by determining
>   the `max-content` size of each flex-sized grid track and dividing that
>   size by the respective flex factor to determine a “hypothetical `1fr`
>   size”.
>
> The maximum of those is used as the resolved `1fr` length (the
>   flex fraction), which is then multiplied by each grid track’s flex
>   factor to determine its final size.

Comment: Works really well and is supported in all major browsers. I'm curious whether there is a way for this to work dynamically? As in, without knowing how many columns there are.

Comment: Good solution using `inline-grid` the downside for me here is that you have to know the number of buttons upfront.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using CSS Grid working with any number of buttons:

```css
div.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

div.container button {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why does `position: absolute` on `.container` break this mechanism?

Comment: because `position: absolute` does not make any sens to for `inline` elements. See this answers for a longer explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042666/1510070

Answer (score 1):

To solve this for any number of elements (without needing to know the number in advance):

- Use an inline grid container (`display: inline-grid`).
- Set [`grid-auto-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) to `1fr` so that implicitly created column tracks all have a size of `1fr`, which makes them all the size of the largest column in this case. To allow the children to shrink past their default minimum size (possibly cutting off content) to maintain equally sized columns, use `minmax(0, 1fr)`.
- Set [`grid-auto-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) to `column`, so that new columns (rather than rows) are created when elements are added to the grid.

```js
document.querySelector('#addBtn').addEventListener('click', e => 
  document.querySelector('.container').append(
    Object.assign(document.createElement('button'), 
      {textContent: document.querySelector('input').value})));
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <button>a normal button</button>
   <button>tiny</button>
   <button>a really, really, really wide button</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <input placeholder="Button text" />
  <button id="addBtn">Add New Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks @Unmitigated!

Comment: @Paul-Hebert Happy to help.