# How to equally size spans with flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div span {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&laquo;</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>&hellip;</span>
  <span>998</span>
  <span>999</span>
  <span>1000</span>
  <span>&raquo;</span>
</div>
```

I'd like the spans to automatically grow equally to the largest elements width.
I'd also like to use `flex` since I don't know in advance how many `<span>`s I'll end up with.

If I add `width: 100%;` to the `<div>` the behaviour essentially works, but the overall component becomes much wider than it'd need to be.

I've also tried adding `display: inline-block;` to the `<span>`s to no avail.

How do I make my spans grow to equal width but no wider?

Comment: display:inline-grid; grid-auto-columns:1fr; grid-auto-flow:column to parent element (I know the duplicate, will search for it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48010604/8620333

Answer (score -1):

Use the display flex for parents also. you can give fixed-width manually, or it will divide the available space equally.

```css
div {
  display:flex;
}

div span {
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>&laquo;</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>&hellip;</span>
  <span>998</span>
  <span>999</span>
  <span>1000</span>
  <span>&raquo;</span>
</div>
```