# What is the behaviour of using position and display together in CSS?

Tags: css, position, footer, display, absolute

I am trying to make a footer at the bottom of the page which has 100% width. Using `position: absolute;`. I can achieve footer positioned at the bottom with the given code. However even after I add `display: block;` I can not get 100% width footer. I am wondering what is the using these two together in terms of positioning. For example does position override display value? Thank you in advance.

```
footer {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    /* display: block; */
    bottom: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: rgba(232, 232, 228, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #fcd5ce;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that are `position: absolute` behave the same as elements with `display: block`, so your `display` has no effect. Here's a good explanation: [CSS: display:inline-block and positioning:absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042467/css-displayinline-block-and-positioningabsolute)

Setting `width: 100%` should fix your problem.